# How to access a model two levels deep in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I am trying to access a nested model two levels deep in rails.

For example, trying to use the .count method to access the all of the likes a users has for their blog posts.

Running `@user.posts.count` returns the correct number of posts per user.

But,

Running `@user.posts.likes.count` returns an error: 'undefined method likes'.

Does anyone know how to access a model two levels deep?

Comment: What kind of object is  `likes` in this case?  `.count` only works on arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@user.posts` will return you an array
And you cannot call an association over an array

Try

```
@user.posts.map(&:likes).flatten.count
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your User has many Posts and each post has many likes.
So `@user.posts.likes.count` will definitely give you error.
However you can get that by finding one **post** and then the **likes** of that post. And the model relationship between Post and Like should be one is-to many . Which means one post has many likes.